# Shiny-server on ubuntu 16 error: "unable to open connection to X11 display ''

Tags: ubuntu, shiny, rstudio, shinydashboard

I'm trying to run a shiny dashboard on an Ubuntu 16 aws ec2 and the sample is partially working: it shows the dashboard controls but and error message instead of the graphs.

Error log out put at /var/log/shinyserver:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:35434
Warning in pngfun(filename = filename, width = width, height = height, res = res,  :
  unable to open connection to X11 display ''
Warning: Error in .External2: unable to start device PNG
  123: pngfun
  122: startPNG
  121: drawPlot
  107: <reactive:plotObj>
   91: drawReactive
   78: origRenderFunc
   77: output$distPlot
    1: runApp
```

From shiny-server.conf at /etc/shiny-server:

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as ubuntu;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```

I tried a few packages prior to R installation: xorg-dev and libx11-dev 
But they didn't help:

Image of the error:[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in the way I installed R-3.4.0 over r-base that must not include support for x11. Correct way was to first update keys, here:

```
apt-get install -y qpdf libx11-dev libpng12-dev libjpeg62
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

instead of:

```
wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.4.0.tar.gz
tar -xzf R-3.4.0.tar.gz
./configure --with-x=yes --enable-R-shlib=yes --with-cairo=yes – without-x11
make
make install
```

The first one installs 3.4.0 base r which was up-to-date enough for my case.